# stack dump while using malloc

Tags: c

Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    char * pt[3];
    size_t size = sizeof(char);


    pt[0] = (char *) malloc(60 * size);
    pt[1] = (char *) malloc(60 * size);
    pt[2] = (char *) malloc(60 * size);

    pt[0] = "Earth";
    puts(pt[0]);

    puts("===================================\n");

    pt[1] = "University";
    puts(pt[1]);

    puts("===================================\n");

    pt[2] = "Things are very interesting!";
    puts(pt[2]);

    puts("===================================\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        free(pt[i]);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Now, program prints as expected. But there is some error at the end

`cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.stackdump`

I tried to put some printf statements and I found that `free` statement is creating some error. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Do you already have experience with higher-level languages by any change? You're doing string assignments in a way that seems influenced by intuitions/expectations built up in other languages.

Comment: The way to fill the buffers allocated is to use `strcpy()` or something similar. (Re-)assigning the pointer(s) after the allocation is not how it's done...

Comment: p=malloc(); p=“Earth”; this forever loses the allocated memory and replaces the pointer p with a read only allocation by the compiler of “Earth”.

Comment: Yes, I know Python. So, may be that influenced this. I will try to use strcpy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not freeing the same pointers you allocated, because a statement like `pt[0] = "Earth";` is overwriting the address in `pt[0]` with the address of the hard-coded string "Earth".

So by the time that `free` runs in your code, it tries to deallocate the wrong memory address.

At that point, either `free` was coded to check for this possibility and it deliberately crashed the program instead of doing bad things, or `free` tried to trustingly do things that it wasn't supposed to based on the address you gave it, and got killed by modern safety features of the OS (for example, when a program runs, modern operating systems will load hard-coded strings into a memory page marked read-only, so the program gets a fatal-by-default signal if it tries to write there).

Why would `free` do stuff it wasn't supposed to do when given a bad address? Because one way that memory allocators have been traditionally written is to allocate slightly larger chunks then you asked for and store metadata for that allocation at the front of that space, and/or to write metadata needed for reusing that memory into the space once you've freed it. In allocators like that, every `free` leads to some memory being overwritten near the address you gave it. This kind of design has led to many bugs and exploitable security vulnerabilities in code, but last I checked it persists in some C implementations.

---

Now onto your bigger-picture goal:

You were seemingly expecting `=` to *copy the characters* from one location to the other. This can make sense when coming from higher-level languages, but C doesn't have such syntactic sugar. Instead, in C, `=` on a memory address ("pointer") copies the memory address.

It's also probably not obvious, but in C, a string literal expression mostly works like a pointer - the type of the expression `"Earth"` is actually `char *`.

Anyway, as others have pointer out, you would use a function like `strcpy` to copy the characters from "Earth" into the newly-allocated storage. You could also copy the characters yourself with a loop, but this isn't recommended in most cases because the standard library implementation: says what you mean in a way that C devs can immediately understand; might be optimized to perform better than a naive byte-by-byte loop, and; might be understood by your compiler's optimizer passes.

Comment: Using `strcpy` stopped that error. I think string literals have their own address. That was the cause of the error.

Comment: @user9026 Right, that's what I was getting at: a string like "Earth" has its own address (at a fundamental level: how could a string literal not have an address? those characters have to be encoded *somewhere* in the program), and when you had `pt[0] = "Earth";` that address of "Earth" overwrote the address that was initially assigned in `pt[0] = malloc(...);`. Anyway, I've finished expanding my answer, which might further clarify some things about why it this causes an overt error once the code reaches `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Since constant string store in program data segment read-only arena and you can't just free it!!
use strcpy to copy str to your allocated memory instead

Understanding application binary segement is really important
in c, have these segments :

Stack
Heap
BSS  (Uninitialized Data Segment)
Data ( has initialized read-only and initialized read-write area)
Code (contains executable instructions)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the program is attempting to release memory that has already been released or memory that was not dynamically allocated using the malloc function . To resolve this problem, use a method like strcpy() to copy the contents of the string literals into the memory allotted by malloc() .